# Does a browser perform selection of corresponding Javascript to screen elements?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

Right Click, `inspect element` allows me to see corresponding `html & css` to screen element. Does the browser likewise, permit tracing the `javascript function` to corresponding clicks? Or do you manually need to trace from `onclick` event, so on and so forth?

If so, can one likewise, perform editing of the Javascript, in a browser to verify, what changes will it bring about? Much like, what we can do for `html & css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Google Chrome i discover, in `Elements` on the right side screen, one can browse to `Event Listners` then `click` event to see some Javascript. I'm still deciphering it to see if it permits simultaneous browser screen manipulation.

It doesn't seem to be working at the moment.